# Proving inequality with absolute value in ordered field

Tags: calculus, field-theory

> In an ordered field $F$, containing 3 members: $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$
>   $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$
>
> Prove that for every $x \in F$:
>   $$|x-a_1| + |x-a_2| + |x-a_3| \ge a_3 - a_1$$
>   (Hint: when $x=a_2$: $|x-a_1| + |x-a_2| + |x-a_3| = a_3 - a_1$)
>
> What you can use:
>   Axioms of a general field (commutativity, associativity, member + (-member) = 0, member * 1/member = 1 (member != 0))
>
> Axioms of ordered field (transitivity, consistency in addition, consistency in multiplication (if $x>0$), trichotomoy ($x=0$ or $x>0$ or $x<0$))
>
> - $0 \le |x|$
> - $|-x| = |x|$
> - $-|x| \le x \le |x|$
> - $|x| \le r \iff -r \le x \le r$
> - $|x+y| \le |x| + |y|$
> - $||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|$

Comment: Please learn MathJax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax

Comment: Improved it a little :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the triangle inequality, adding the third term only makes the greater side even greater. The challenge may be to write it down citing all the rules at the appropriate places.